# How to show NSTextView-like context menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, contextmenu, nstextview, appkit

I want to present NSTextView-like context menu for a certain `NSString` object (say, "text") each time `-rightMouseDown`-method of my custom `NSResponder`-subclass get called.

[image]

Where can I obtain these items for some `NSString`?

**UPD**

Created `NSTextView` instance and used its `-menuForEvent:`-method. Some of items was disabled (like 'copy' and so on), I reset its target value to custom object with overridden selectors (like `-copy:` and others).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSTextView` is an `NSView` subclass, which [provides a class method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSView/defaultMenu) `+defaultMenu`. So you can ask for `NSMenu * menu = [NSTextView defaultMenu];` to get your very own copy to do with as you please. You may have to walk its structure and customize individual `NSMenuItem` instances to adjust their target/action but most (all?) should work just fine with nil-target (sends action to first responder) and their default action.

I must admit, however, I'm not sure what you mean by "Where can I obtain these items for some `NSString`?" The context menu is opened from some UI control (like a text view) and sends its action (like `-checkSpelling...`) to some target (like the first responder; which should be something like a text view, which acts as the view for a string or attributed string) to act upon.

Comment: (I updated this to add the second paragraph after an up-vote - up-voter, please re-read.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the class method returns menu with items completely different with those I gave in the OP-post. Looks like the menu I'm looking for is creating somewhere inside `NSTextView`-instance according to its selected text range. (Edited question to be more clear)

Comment: Hmmm... is your view a *direct* subclass of NSResponder? If so (and it handles text), why not make it a subclass of at least NSText if not NSTextView? That way, you get all the behavior "for free". Failing that, maintain an off-screen text view, feed it your text, then ask it for its `-menuForEvent:`... (in other words, "fake it"). ;-)